# How do I connect a <form>, <select> and a <div> slider to a button in HTML?

Tags: html

I have to connect a  tag, three  tags and a  that contains a slider to a  that is connected to a database.

I have made all of the elements but they are in no way connected to each other, and pressing the button does nothing.

Here is the form where the user types their points:

```
 <form id="pointsform">
    Points:<input type="number">
    </form>
```

Then I have the user select a subject:

```
<select id="subject-selection">
  <option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
  <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
  <option value="English">English</option>
</select>
```

Then they choose the year:

```
<select id="year-selection">
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
```

Then they choose the season:

```
<select id="season-selection">
  <option value="Spring">Kevät</option>
  <option value="Fall">Syksy</option>
</select>
```

Then they can choose a value from a slider:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <p id="slider">How strictly did your teacher grade:</p>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
```

Under all of that there is a button:

```
<button id="compare-button">Compare</button>
```

I would like to connect all the user inputted answers to the button, so when I click the button, it interacts with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to wrap everything into a single form like this:

```html
<form id="pointsform">
    <input type="number">
    <select id="subject-selection">
        <option value="Math">Math</option>
        <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
        <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
        <option value="English">English</option>
    </select>
    <select id="year-selection">
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
    </select>
    <select id="season-selection">
        <option value="Spring">Kevät</option>
        <option value="Fall">Syksy</option>
    </select>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <p id="slider">How strictly did your teacher grade:</p>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Compare">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! But now when I click the button nothing happens. How can I get the button to interact with the database using the given information by the user?

Comment: @JukkaK18 Please mark this answer as accepted and feel free to ask a new question about your new request (interact with database) on the site, but I'd advise you to study jQuery and AJAX and try it yourself before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Put **all** the form controls *inside* the `<form>` element, not just the `<input type="number">`.